# NASM FindFirstFileA LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA

Tags: winapi, nasm, 32-bit

I've written a basic program in NASM trying to use FindFileA with a view to eventually listing all files in a directory.

```
extern FindFirstFileA               ; kernel32.dll
extern ExitProcess              ; kernel32.dll

section .code

    Start:
        push    dataStructPtr
        push    searchParameters
        call    [FindFirstFileA]
        mov [fileHandle], eax       

        push    0
        call    [ExitProcess]

section .data
    searchParameters: db "*.*",0    

section .bss
    dataStructPtr:  resb 4
    fileHandle:     resb 4
```

As far as I can tell a 32-bit pointer to the WIN32_FIND_DATAA structure should be going into address 402008.

However it looks like more than 4 bytes are being written and also that gives me an address of 007334C8 which the program memory does not go up to.

Would you be able to shed some light on why this is happening and where the structure resides so I could look at it using OllyDbg?

Using OllyDbg to look at it:

[image]

[image]

Many Thanks

Comment: `FindFirstFile` doesn't allocate the memory; you have to give it a pointer to a pre-allocated `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure. All you're giving it is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: `sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATAA)` needed instead of 4 bytes (`resb 4`). In C++ code like this: `HANDLE fileHandle;
 WIN32_FIND_DATAA dataStruct;
 fileHandle = FindFirstFileA(searchParameters, &dataStruct);`